# Progress bars with color and borders with common controls

Tags: visual-c++, win32gui, common-controls

I had colorful progress bars in my GUI that I liked:

[image: Original]

However, I wanted the GUI to look be in the Windows 7 style when on Windows 7, so I added this pragma

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' \
language='*'\"")
```

But this resulted in monochrome (green), animated **glowing** toolbars that I don't like:

[image: glowing]

So I removed the styles by entering:

```
  SetWindowTheme(hProgress, L" ", L" ");
```

The results where not bad:

[image: Borderless]

However, note that there's no border around the progress bar though I rely on the same resource file.
How do I set the progress bar to the original look while retaining the Windows 7 look for the rest of the window?

Comment: Turn on the "Static edge" style for them, looks fairly reasonable.

Comment: @HansPassant: Well this was not the solution but I somehow stambled upon it: `SetWindowPos(hCh, HWND_TOP, 1,1,1,1, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);`

Answer (score 3):

When Visual Styles are enabled, a standard Win32 ProgressBar does not support custom coloring, it gets its coloring from the current theme instead.  That is why your ProgressBars all turned green.  However, you can use the [`PBM_SETSTATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760850.aspx) message to set the ProgressBar's state to `PBST_NORMAL` (green), `PBST_ERROR` (red), or `PBST_PAUSED` (yellow).

Beyond that, to display a themed ProgressBar with custom colors, you have to owner-draw a custom control using [`DrawThemeBackground()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289.aspx) directly, drawing the [various components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773210.aspx) of the `"PROGRESS"` class as needed. The standard red, green, cyan, and yellow colors can be drawn by setting the `iStateId` parameter to `PBFS_ERROR`, `PBFS_NORMAL`, `PBFS_PARTIAL`, or `PBFS_PAUSED` (respectively) when drawing the `PP_FILL` portion (the colored bar showing the current progress).  If you need any other colors, though, it gets a bit trickier.  The following article shows an example of drawing a standard themed ProgressBar with a gradient color blend:

[Gradient Bar Control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488893/Gradient-Bar-Control)

The technique demonstrated draws a standard ProgressBar first using the `PBFS_NORMAL` (green) state, then uses HSL saturation and intensity transformations to alter the color values of the `PP_FILL` pixels to make them into the desired colors.

Comment: Following message only helped me to change ProgressBar color. "However, you can use the PBM_SETSTATE message to set the ProgressBar's state to PBST_NORMAL (green), PBST_ERROR (red), or PBST_PAUSED (yellow)."

Answer (score 0):

Change style of progress bar with write this manifest:

```
 <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
manifestVersion="1.0">
 <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <security>
       <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" 
   uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="Win32" 
    name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 
    version="6.0.0.0"
                    processorArchitecture="*" 
     publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
```

and this resource:

```
1 24"manifestname.manifest"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem but didn't manage to enable the borders.
However by changing the background of the bars it looks okay:

```
SendMessage(hwndPBAR, PBM_SETBKCOLOR, 0, 0x00DCDCDC); //grey
```